# Code implementation for Protocol

Tags: c, protocols, pic, modbus, crc16

I am trying to Implement Modbus RTU with function code 1 . **I have already written code on Modbus RTU with function code 3 where i can send request & get response properly**.I am trying to get modify the code for function code 1. With below code There is no issue with CRC function because i could able to see calculation going write as per Simply modbus website.

**CRC error check function**

```
unsigned int crc_fn(unsigned char *dpacket,unsigned int len) // CRC Function(Error calcualtion)
{
 unsigned int crc = 0xffff,poly = 0xa001;
 unsigned int i=0; 

 for(i=0;i<len;i++)
 {
    crc^= dpacket[i];
    for(j=0;j<8;j++)
    {
     if(crc & 0x01)
     {
      crc >>= 1;
      crc ^= poly;
     }
     else
    crc >>= 1;
    }
 }
 return (crc); 
}
```

**Request & Response function**

```
 void Serial_Data()
{


    unsigned int address,crc1,crc2;
 unsigned char length,i;
    unsigned char Data_Len_Count;
    unsigned char length1;


    // Serial_1_Send_byte(rxbuf[0]);
    crc2=crc_fn(&rxbuf[0],6); //crc function for received protocol from request 
         __delay_ms(10); // Changed on 20.01.2017
  if((rxbuf[6]==(unsigned char)(crc2))&&(rxbuf[7]==((unsigned char)(crc2>>8))))
     {

  if(rxbuf[0]==Device_ID )
  {

   if(rxbuf[1]==READ_REG)
   {
    address=(((unsigned int)(rxbuf[2]<<8))+((unsigned int)(rxbuf[3]))); 
    if(rxbuf[5]>=1)
    {

     length1=(rxbuf[5]<249)?(rxbuf[5]+7)/8:0X20;
                    length=(rxbuf[5]*1);
     address=(address*1); 
     ser_data[0]=Device_ID ;
     ser_data[1]=rxbuf[1];
     ser_data[2]=length; 
     ser_data[3]=rxbuf[6];
     ser_data[4]=rxbuf[7];
     ser_data[5]=length1;
     ser_data[6]=00;
     ser_data[7]=00;
     ser_data[8]=00;
     ser_data[9]=00; 


     crc_data[0]=Device_ID ;
     crc_data[1]=rxbuf[1];
     crc_data[2]=length;

     j=3;
     for(i=address;i<((address+length));i++)
     {
      crc_data[j++]=ser_data[i+3];
                       // ChecksumCal(length);
     }
     crc1 =crc_fn(&crc_data[0],(length+3)); //crc function for response protocol from the device

                    Serial_1_Send_byte(ser_data[0]);
     Serial_1_Send_byte(rxbuf[1]);
     Serial_1_Send_byte(ser_data[2]);

     for(i=address;i<((address+length));i++)
     {
      Serial_1_Send_byte(ser_data[i+3]);

     }
     Serial_1_Send_byte((unsigned char)crc1);
     Serial_1_Send_byte((unsigned char)(crc1>>8));
                     Serial_1_Send_byte(crc_msb);
                             Serial_1_Send_byte(crc_lsb);



                    for(i=0;i<30;i++)
                    {
                       Serial_1_Send_byte(0);
                    }

    } 
   } 
   __delay_ms(5); 
       }

 }
  index=0;
 rec_flag = 0;

}
```

**The main problem i am suspecting here is function code 3 data send in byte & function code 1 send data in bits. because of which i am suspecting request going well but when response it popout checksum error in modbus message**

[image]

Comment: Are you packing your coils correctly?

Comment: my suspection on Serial_data() ie packing of data  i am not packing coils properly. FC3 uses byte so data packed in byte format where as FC1 uses bits of data so data should be packed in bits converted to byte send for crc check. How can i bit of digital io status to byte of data and send for crc check. if u see image input request going properly but response showing error